# How do I make a 1 minute delay circuit?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to make a circuit with a delay of 600 ticks. I looked this up on the Minecraft wiki and found the following diagram:

[image: 600 tick delay]

However, when I tried it, I couldn't get it to work. How can I make a 1 minute delay circuit? A picture of one such finished circuit would be ideal.

Comment: Also, you do realize that's 5 minutes and 8 seconds, not 1 minute?  You want your two clocks to be 24 ticks and 25 ticks, not 55 and 56.

Comment: @mbraedley the save all timer doesn't answer my question, as i am specifically looking for 1 minute... a friend answered my question (i needed a pulse, not a current), but thank you for informing me this one wouldnt have worked anyway. i didnt sleep enough last night >.< thanks though!

Comment: Between my comment, and the information found in fredley's answer, you should have everything you need.  If you choose to go with a hopper design, Etho's video will have everything you need.

Comment: Please describe your problem in detail. This applies more to software dev and [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/), but we devs like to ask ["What have you tried?"](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) when a question doesn't say exactly what the asker has tried and why and how it didn't work.